# What else affects game stats gained during tasks?

Tags: game-dev-story

Other than the obvious effect of employee stats and the explanation that using one employee on the same job too many times in a row will decrease effectiveness, what else determines how many points are put into the game?

I had one employee consistently give me high points in Fun while writing the proposal (between 70 and 90). I always made sure to swap him out so that he wouldn't get burnt out by the "PREV" tag. However, this morning he really let me down and produced a game proposal that I would expect out of a fresh college grad, not a 15 year veteran in the industry. It looked like he just gave up after "3 times" and I got just under 30 points of Fun from his proposal.

I still topped the charts, but it concerned me. Are there other factors that go into this determination, such as genre combination, energy level, morale, motivation, etc? I've come to depend on my employees to produce high quality games. Are they one day going to let me down? Will I be able to see it coming? Can I prevent it??

Comment: I believe that matching genre/type increases the points gained, while a mismatched genre/type decreases the points gained - I've had 200+ stat workers go 3 times and give 30 points to a game that had a bad genre and type combination.

Comment: That could be it. I know he was working on a sequel, but I don't remember if he worked on the original or what the points were...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that there is a probability involved every time you run the task. When you use a hacker with great stats, most of the time they will produce, however I'm betting it's a simple percent chance that they will/won't, similar to when your workers ask if they can 'improve' a specific stat and the highest percent chance you can attain is 80%.

I've tested these variables all at once:
1. 'Amazing' genre/type combination
2. Maxed out direction
   a. Both fully maxed out, and only maxed out for what I feel is needed for that specific combination
3. High level staff member who is in the key job for the task (Scenario/Writer, Graphics/Designer, etc)
4. Full energy bar

And on occasion, they still won't produce. I'm quite sure that of course a higher stat staff member reduces the chance of a bad outcome, but the bad outcome still remains.